# Graph hangs, button duplicates when loading in Chrome 10

Tags: support, reputation-graph

Can anyone reproduce this in Chrome 10?

- Open the profile of (preferably a high-rep) user
- Switch to the "reputation" tab
- Switch to the "Graph" tab. The tab must not be pre-set to "graph" already
- The "graph" button will duplicate:

  http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/0.04672800%201301396962.png
- The calculation will never finish
- If you switch to a different tab and back, there will eventually be the graph, and two "graph" buttons.

  http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/0.41833100%201301396955.png

  Sometimes, the second graph button will lead to another graph being shown above the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to update/uninstall balpha's script

[Reputation graph](https://stackapps.com/questions/2202/reputation-graph)

Comment: Indeed. This makes sense. Will accept in 10 minutes